# avoid replacement when using lapply

Tags: r

I would like to ask a question about lapply. As we can see from the following example, when we implement it on an object it leaves the object unchanged.

```
List <- list("Obj" = list())

List$Obj[[1]] <- 1
List$Obj[[2]] <- 2
print(List)

f <- function(x, a) x <- a
b <- 3
lapply(X=List$Obj, FUN=f, b) 
print(List)                  # List$Obj remains unchanged
```

One solution is to send the outcome of lapply to the object itself.

```
List$Obj <- lapply(X=List$Obj, FUN=f, b) # a first option
```

Is there another, more efficient, way of doing it from within lapply and avoid replacement?

Thank you in advance

Comment: That is quite pointless - `lapply` is called because of its result which you are discarding. You could have simply used `for` instead if you wanted to have a loop. But that is not a way you would design code in R.